# Mysql - select last row for each user

Tags: mysql, message

this is my query :

```
 SELECT msgId as `ID`,msgFromUserId , msgToUserId ,  
            DATE_FORMAT( msgDate,'%d/%m/%y %H:%i') as `time` ,  MID(msgText,1,30) as `text` , 
            (CASE WHEN (msgFromUserId=292646) then  b.user_login else  a.user_login END) as `sender`
            FROM tbl_messages inner join wp_users as a on tbl_messages.msgFromUserId=a.ID 
            inner join wp_users as b on tbl_messages.msgToUserId=b.ID 
            inner join tbl_forum_users u1 on tbl_messages.msgFromUserId=u1.user_ID 
            inner join tbl_forum_users u2 on tbl_messages.msgToUserId=u2.user_ID 
where (msgFromUserId=292646 or msgToUserId=292646)
and tbl_messages.msgId in (SELECT max(msgId) FROM tbl_messages   GROUP BY msgFromUserId, msgToUserId )
order by msgId desc
```

i get this :

[image: result table]

I dont want duplication row. Just get the last line of conversation between them

Comment: You can do is `Order DESC` you get the rows from `last to first` order and then `LIMIT 1` you get the only last row ie. first row

Comment: Don't You have a serious problem with table and column definition? record 107 and 26 has the same sender. Shouldn't it vary when there is other 'FromUserId' ?

Comment: Why do you join `tbl_forum_users`? Where do you use `u1` and `u2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast fix could be to change your subquery

```
SELECT max(msgId) FROM tbl_messages   GROUP BY msgFromUserId, msgToUserId
```

to

```
SELECT max(msgId) 
FROM tbl_messages
GROUP BY LEAST(msgFromUserId, msgToUserId), GREATEST(msgFromUserId, msgToUserId)
```

This will group messages from 292646 to 1 and from 1 to 292646 together.

Complete query:

```
SELECT msgId as `ID`,msgFromUserId , msgToUserId ,  
            DATE_FORMAT( msgDate,'%d/%m/%y %H:%i') as `time` ,  MID(msgText,1,30) as `text` , 
            (CASE WHEN (msgFromUserId=292646) then  b.user_login else  a.user_login END) as `sender`
            FROM tbl_messages inner join wp_users as a on tbl_messages.msgFromUserId=a.ID 
            inner join wp_users as b on tbl_messages.msgToUserId=b.ID 
            inner join tbl_forum_users u1 on tbl_messages.msgFromUserId=u1.user_ID 
            inner join tbl_forum_users u2 on tbl_messages.msgToUserId=u2.user_ID 
where (msgFromUserId=292646 or msgToUserId=292646)
and tbl_messages.msgId in (
    SELECT max(msgId) 
    FROM tbl_messages
    GROUP BY LEAST(msgFromUserId, msgToUserId), GREATEST(msgFromUserId, msgToUserId)
)
order by msgId desc
```

To improve the performance you should also move the user-id-condition into the subquery:

```
SELECT max(msgId) 
FROM tbl_messages
where (msgFromUserId=292646 or msgToUserId=292646) -- <-- here
GROUP BY LEAST(msgFromUserId, msgToUserId), GREATEST(msgFromUserId, msgToUserId)
```

To use the indexes the best way you should use a UNION ALL optimisation. But this is going to look pretty complex:

```
SELECT max(msgId)
FROM (
    SELECT msgToUserId as otherUserId, max(msgId) as msgId
    FROM tbl_messages 
    WHERE msgFromUserId=292646 
    GROUP BY msgToUserId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT msgFromUserId as otherUserId, max(msgId) as msgId
    FROM tbl_messages 
    WHERE msgToUserId=292646 
    GROUP BY msgFromUserId
) sub
GROUP BY otherUserId
```

Note this is only the subquery to use in the WHERE clause (`tbl_messages.msgId in (...)`).

This subquery can also be used as a derived table, so we can join it with `tbl_messages`:

```
SELECT msgId as `ID`,
       msgFromUserId,
       msgToUserId,  
       DATE_FORMAT( msgDate,'%d/%m/%y %H:%i') as `time`,
       MID(msgText,1,30) as `text` , 
       (CASE WHEN (msgFromUserId=292646) then  b.user_login else  a.user_login END) as `sender`
FROM (
    SELECT max(msgId) as msgId
    FROM (
        SELECT msgToUserId as otherUserId, max(msgId) as msgId
        FROM tbl_messages 
        WHERE msgFromUserId=292646 
        GROUP BY msgToUserId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT msgFromUserId as otherUserId, max(msgId) as msgId
        FROM tbl_messages 
        WHERE msgToUserId=292646 
        GROUP BY msgFromUserId
    ) sub
    GROUP BY otherUserId
) sub
inner join tbl_messages on tbl_messages.msgId = sub.msgId
inner join wp_users as a on tbl_messages.msgFromUserId=a.ID 
inner join wp_users as b on tbl_messages.msgToUserId=b.ID 
inner join tbl_forum_users u1 on tbl_messages.msgFromUserId=u1.user_ID 
inner join tbl_forum_users u2 on tbl_messages.msgToUserId=u2.user_ID 
order by tbl_messages.msgId desc
```

You need the following indexes to support the subquery:

```
tbl_messages(msgFromUserId, msgToUserId [, msgId])
tbl_messages(msgToUserId, msgFromUserId [, msgId])
```